Lazy load page components vs ES6 Imports
I m working on a project we are using lazy loading in route level in APP.
import { Suspense, lazy } from 'react';

const AppRoutes = lazy(() =>
  import(/* webpackChunkName: "App" */ './routes/RouteConfig.jsx')
);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={lightTheme}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <AppRoutes />
        <Toaster
          richColors
          visibleToasts={3}
          position='top-right'
          closeButton={false}
          gap={12}
          pauseWhenPageIsHidden={true}
          duration={1500}
          expand={false}
        />
      </ThemeProvider>
      </Suspense>
    </>
  );
}


My Question is should we lazy loading in page level as well?
eg: I m building a marketing in that i m spliting each sections in components to import them in MarketingPage.jsx should i go through ES6 imports or lazy loading ?
import { Suspense, lazy } from 'react';

const Cards = lazy(() => import('../../components/Cards'));
const Hero = lazy(() => import('./Hero'));
const InSightsHub = lazy(() => import('./InSightsHub'));
const InfoScreen = lazy(() => import('./InfoScreen'));
const InvestWithGenie = lazy(() => import('./InvestWithGenie'));
const Investment = lazy(() => import('./Investment'));
const Portfolio = lazy(() => import('./Portfolio'));

export default function MarketingPage() {
  return (
    <>
      <Suspense fallback={'Loading...'}>
        <Hero />
        <Investment />
        <InvestWithGenie />
        <InfoScreen />
        <Portfolio />
        <InSightsHub />
        <Cards />
      </Suspense>
    </>
  );
}


Kindly please explain should i use or not, And if should't use why we should't use and where are the best practices to use lazy load.

Lets evaluate why would we need to use lazy-loading in the first place and what happens when you wrap components in lazy(() => import('/SomeComponent'))?
By default, most of the bundlers create at least two .js files:

vendor.js - with the dependencies from node_modules like react, react-router, etc. For the small apps 90-95% of the bytes of js user will have to download falls on vendor bundle.
app.js/index.js - this is all your app code.

Every time you use lazy(), you tell webpack/vite to put the component and its dependencies (it is more nuanced but lets simplify) into separate js file. And do not load this file, unless user will try to render this component. When it happen first the app will try to load this js file with the component, and only then will render it. Which leads to worse user experience. In case of really heavy pages/components (think facebook for example) it might make sense to have parts of the apps out from main bundle, but for the smaller apps, it almost always unnecessary.
So, the right way to do it:

Do not use lazy by default. measure load time for the main bundle.
If you think it is too heavy, try to use lazy for the heaviest and least-used part/component/page of your app.
Repeat measurements again for main bundle and for how long it take user to wait lazy component being loaded. If you see that the inital load-time is now reduced significantly, then it make sense to keep lazy.

